# How are Windows passwords handled?

Tags: windows, passwords

I'm looking for good information about how Windows handles the passwords of its users:

- Which algorithms are used (which hash, do they use salt, ...)?
- Where are the passwords stored?
- Are there known exploits?

Especially interesting are Windows XP, Vista and 7.

I was not able to find useful information with Google, most pages are talking about resetting or cracking tools, but I'm interested in the theory.

Comment: NTLM, LM hash, Kerberos. Looking up those things should give you some insight, I think.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> Which algorithms are used (which hash, do they use salt, ...)

Two hashes are stored: **[LM hash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LM_hash)** for [LanMan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_LAN_Manager), and a **[MD4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD4) hash** (also called "NT hash") for NTLM.

**Only the MD4 hash is normally used.** It is not salted, since the SAM database is only accessible to the `Administrators` group and to `NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM` internal account.

The LM hash is only stored for compatibility reasons. (See paragraph below.) It is very insecure (its history starts with OS/2 and MS-DOS), and crackable in (I think) minutes. Windows only uses it when logging in to old servers; however, if stored it can be extracted with a LiveCD or such.

In Windows 7, storing of LM hashes is disabled. In earlier releases you can disable it manually in security policies (`secpol.msc` → Local Policies → Security Options → *Network Security: Do not store LAN Manager hash*).

---

> Where are the passwords stored?

**[Security Accounts Manager](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_Account_Manager) database** - a part of Registry, stored under `%SystemRoot%\system32\config\`.

Since Windows 2000, the SAM database is **additionally encrypted** by default. `<afaik>` The key is scattered all over the (same) registry file, but is still recoverable. `</afaik>` But if you want, you can [move the encryption key](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310105) to a floppy drive, or to use an additional password. (You will be asked for it on boot.) This is done using [SYSKEY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SYSKEY) (`syskey.exe`)

(SYSKEY support was added in NT 4.0 SP3, but disabled by default until W2000.)

---

> Are there known exploits?

Cracking LM hashes? More than you can imagine.
[MD4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD4) seems to be more secure, but be sure to read that Wikipedia article.

---

On Windows 9x series - [don't expect](http://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/~pgut001/pubs/pwl.txt) anything [better than ROT26](http://web.archive.org/web/19981206192119/http://www.geek-girl.com/bugtraq/1995_4/0138.html).

Comment: Great answer with lots of useful links ... I heard today that windows xp passwords can be cracked in a few minutes - that's why I asked. I thought they are saved with SHA1/2 + salt, so I just couldn't imagine how to crack them within minutes ... but your answer explains all ... thank you

Comment: Great answer for DOS, Win9x,Win2K, but I don't understand where's the WinXP,7,8:)

Comment: @SEARAS: So far, all Windows NT series operating systems (NT 4.0, 2000, XP, Server 2003, 7, Server 2008, 8) use the same SAM. (The only difference is that Win7 and newer versions stopped storing the LM hash.)