# Where does Windows OS store user passwords?

Tags: windows, passwords

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How are windows passwords handled?](https://superuser.com/questions/118233/how-are-windows-passwords-handled)

can someone give me idea regarding how passwords are being stored inside the windows operating system?

Comment: Sure, want my credit card information too?

Comment: What version of Windows? In a domain?

Comment: That's a horrible title.

Comment: @George it's not terribly private. Everyone knows that your windows passwords are about as secure as your birthday. Ever heard of ophcrack?

Comment: Title changed to something a little more accurate

Answer (score 8):

Normally, Windows store passwords on single computer systems in the registry in a hashed format using the NTLM algorithm.  The registry file is located in

```
C:\windows\system32\config\SAM.
```

This area of the registry has restrictive permissions so that a normal user cannot see the contents of `HKLM\SAM` deep enough to access the hash.  In order to view the hashes one must change the permissions on the registry keys, this requires an administrative account on the system in Windows XP.  I am unsure if access is possible using an administrator account in Vista or 7.

Once one has access to the password hashes though, it is difficult to gain the passwords again.  There are many places on the internet that you can find information about brute forcing a NTLM hash.  However, if you are simply trying to reset a password, I would recommend using Offline NT Password and Registry Editor.

If you want to get your arms wet though, the hash is stored under the key

```
HKLM\SAM\SAM\Domains\Account\Users\00000XXX
```

with a value named `V`.  The hash is stored at a variable offset that is stored at offset `0x9C` and is a 4 byte little endian value.

Answer (score 7):

They are hashed using the [NTLMv2 algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTLMv2#NTLMv2) and stored in the [SAM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_Account_Manager).