# How can I change/erase Windows password using Ubuntu Live?

Tags: windows, linux, passwords, password-management, password-recovery

How can I change or erase the Windows XP password from [Ubuntu Live](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_Live_USB_creator) (11.04) booted on the PC in question?

I reckon it should be possible, at least it is possible to do so to another Ubuntu installation, but I never knew how to do it to Windows XP.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows: How to reset the administrator password?](http://superuser.com/questions/5039/windows-how-to-reset-the-administrator-password)

Comment: not really, I am looking for ways to do this from nix by accessing the hdd and erasing/modifying the necessary files, which I can do, the question is which files

Comment: [Ok then check here](http://superuser.com/questions/118233/how-are-windows-passwords-handled)  Still a dupe.

Comment: FYI - No chance of *changing* the password - unless you think in MD4 hashes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In [Fedora](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fedora_%28operating_system%29) I used [`chntpw`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chntpw) to wipe out the Windows administrator password. For example:

```
chntpw -i /media/WindowsXP/WINDOWS/system32/config/SAM
```